# Sleep issues (never powers off)

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, sleep

I'm having an issue with my sleep/restart/shut down functions.

-if I choose to restart the computer shuts down
-if I choose to shut down or sleep the screen goes black, the fan runs and the keyboard is not responsive (caps lock doesn't register when clicked)

i haved tried the following with no luck:

- hardware diagnostics checked out
- enabled turning off of wireless network adapter, video and usb to save power in device manager
- updated video drivers (nvidia)
- disabled hybrid sleep
- uninstalled skype

If I attempt to shutdown from safe mode the screen locks on the "Shutting down ..." screen.

Any help would be most appreciated.

This is a new Win7 Ultimate install with all my apps and drivers loaded.

Comment: Whats the update status? All up to date and patched?

Comment: Is the BIOS up to date?

Comment: ErnieTheGeek - yes, ZippyV - yes,  thanks for the ideas!  any others?

Answer (score 0):

Drivers are the primary cause of power state issues. All drivers on the system must support the desired power state in order for that state to work.

While the video drivers are a good start, I would also download any mainboard drivers, network and sound card, if they are discrete components, and check for updates to any other system components that require drivers.

That said, a power down issue appears to be mostly BIOS, from my experience. So definitly check your BIOS for any firmware updates.

Comment: I have installed all the drivers from Dell and the BIOS is up to date.  Is there an easy way to check for out of date drivers?

Comment: Not really. Many drivers are being updated through Windows Update now, so that's becoming more standardized, but they aren't installed unless you choose to install them. They are not automatically pushed with your scheduled update process.